# 'lineterminator' keyword argument not working in csv.read

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have the following data in a file:

```
'#export_date\x01video_id\x01name\x01long_description\x01episode_production_number\x02\n'
```

This seems simple enough to parse, doing:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=u'\x01', lineterminator=u'\x02\n')
```

However, when I do the following, it does not parse the item before the line break properly. Here is what I get:

```
{
    '#export_date': u '1475711237318',
    'video_id': u '382992872'
    'name': u 'Death Lives',
    'long_description': u 'When Peter skips out on his anniversary date with Lois in order to play golf with his buddies, he is inexplicably struck by lightning and visited by Death. Instead of escorting Peter to the after-life, Death tells Peter that Lois will leave him in the future unless Peter uses his near-death experience to come to a life-changing revelation. In order to help him, Death takes Peter back to the moment that Peter and Lois met and fell in love.',
    'episode_production_number\x02': u '2ACX21\x02',
}
```

How would I fix this, and why isn't the lineterminator working here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.lineterminator, the reader ignores the lineterminator keyword argument:

> ```
> Dialect.lineterminator
> ```
>
> The string used to terminate lines produced by the writer. It defaults to '\r\n'.
>
> Note: The reader is hard-coded to recognise either '\r' or '\n' as end-of-line, and ignores lineterminator. This behavior may change in the future.